# What is the correct way to "predefine" and use namespaces and std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, shared-ptr

I have been having a hard time trying to find anything similar to this question, so instead I will ask here.

I have a project with a dozen or so source/header files. The main problem I am having is predefining the classes that I have made in the namespace. The code is as followed:

"GlobalIncludes.h"

```
/*include dependencies and library headers...*/

/*[Note 1]How would I predefine the classes inside namespaces?*/

typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Class1> ClassPtr1;//[Note 2]
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Class2> ClassPtr2;//[Note 2]

/*[Note 2]What is the correct way to predefine the shared_ptr's?*/

#include "Class1.h"
#include "Class2.h"
```

"Class1.h"

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    class Class1
    {
        /*variables and functions*/
        void doSomething(...);
        Class2 exampleObject;
    };
}
```

"Class2.h"

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    class Class2
    {
        /*variables and functions*/
    };
}
```

My apologies in advance if this sounds a bit confusing...
Basically I am wondering if it is possible to predefine the classes that are in `namespace myNamespace` and at the same time declare the `shared_ptr`'s. If this is possible, how would I do this and use them correctly in the source?

Comment: Don't predefine anything, it will just make your code less readable. By using namespace specifiers everybody knows exactly what your type is without wading through other code. (But that is just my opinion)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the type definitions to be part of the same namespace as the classes (which I suggest):

```
namespace my_namespace
{
    class Class1;
    class Class2;

    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Class1> ClassPtr1;
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Class2> ClassPtr2;
}

#include "Class1.h"
#include "Class2.h"
```

Otherwise, if you want your pointer type definitions to be part of the global namespace

```
namespace my_namespace
{
    class Class1;
    class Class2;
}

typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<my_namespace::Class1> ClassPtr1;
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<my_namespace::Class2> ClassPtr2;

#include "Class1.h"
#include "Class2.h"
```

Possibly, you could make things more compact with a macro (same namespace):

```
#define DECLARE_PTR_ALIAS(N, C, P) \
    namespace N { class C; 
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<C> P; } \
```

Or (different namespace):

```
#define DECLARE_PTR_ALIAS(N, C, P) \
    namespace N { class C; } \
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<N::C> P;
```

This would make it simpler to define pointer aliases for several classes:

```
DECLARE_PTR_ALIAS(my_namespace, Class1, ClassPtr1)
DECLARE_PTR_ALIAS(my_namespace, Class2, ClassPtr2)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed reply! I am in the middle of testing this out to see the results.

Comment: With some quick testing I was able to use it more successfully than by myself. Thanks a lot :D EDIT: I also really like the more organized method via `#define`. I use it already, but I didn't think it would work that way.

Answer (score 0):

To pre-declare classes (or functions, or etc...) in a namespace, you do this:

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    class myClassA;
    class myClassB;
}
```

If I'm just pre-declaring a single class, I like to put it on one line: (just personal preference)

```
namespace myNamespace { class myClassA; }
```

In your example, however, Class1 is already in a namespace, so you might as well do it like this:

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    class Class2;

    class Class1
    {
        /*variables and functions*/
        void doSomething(...);
        Class2 exampleObject;
    };
}
```

The only problem is Class1 has Class2 as a member-variable. You can't use pre-declared objects as members, since the compiler needs to know the size of the object to embed it into the class. You can only use pre-declared objects as references or pointers, since those have fixed sizes.

If you made Class2 a smart pointer, then you can do so:

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    class Class2;

    typedef std::shared_ptr<Class2> Class2ptr;

    class Class1
    {
        /*variables and functions*/
        void doSomething(...);
        Class2ptr exampleObject;
    };
}
```

But the shared_ptr has to be fully included and can't be pre-declared, because the shared_ptrs are now member variables and the class needs to know *their* full size.